# How to create a new page with code-behind file in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

When create a new page, I choose XAML View as below image

[image]

But created MyPage.xaml does not have code-behind (*.cs) like App.xaml or MainPage.xaml
How to create a new page with code-behind in *.xaml?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Blank Page template instead of XAML View.
It is the first one in your list